# /usr/bin/env: python3: No such file or directory - Windows 7

Tags: python

I just started to learn Python, but have got stuck on the first page of the tutorials, trying to print "Hello World" from a source file.

http://pymbook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/thebeginning.html

I'm following the instructions to the letter but getting the error above. I've tried installing the 32 bit version on my windows 7 64 bit machine, adjusted the text editor (Sublime Text 2) so that it has Unix line endings. No dice.

Any ideas?

Comment: type "python" in CMD. what you getting?

Comment: I was just using the default install path so I'm now reinstalling to my own path and following the link that sancelot suggested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to setup python3 binary  PATH in your PATH environment variables..
http://www.anthonydebarros.com/2011/10/15/setting-up-python-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 3):

The Windows installation of Python 3.x does not have an executable called `python3` unlike *nix which does. If you change your shebang line to `#!/usr/bin/env python` it will use the Python that is installed.

Answer (score 0):

First type "`python`" in your `CMD`. If you are getting an error

> 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Add location of `python.exe` to your `path` in your `environment variable`.

If the `python.exe` location is "C:\Python34" add

> C:\Python34;
>   to your `path` in your `environment variable`.

To execute a python file using `CMD`
then

> C:\Windows\System32>python test_file.py

Add full file path if `CMD` is not at that location where your file exists.